# Listing directory paths with Unix command

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I need to list out all directory paths which contains .txt files.

For eg: there is a path /geek/ user/ temp.txt .I need to Get the path /geek/user as output ..anyone please advise

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, run this in the Command Prompt (cmd), after positioning
([cd](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)) to the root folder:

```
for /r %a in (.) do @if exist "%~fa\*.txt" echo %~fa
```

Or replace `.` above by the path to the root folder.

For Linux, two possible commands are:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' | sort -u
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u
```

For MacOS:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | sed -E 's|/[^/]+$||' | sort -u
```

Comment: Tried running for /r %a in . do @if exist "%~fa\*.txt"   command with bash but didn't work though..s"yntax error near unexpected token `%a` " is the error message

Comment: Why is your post tagged "windows" if this is for Linux?

Comment: So I added in all the operating systems.